# what does 'can't assign to literal' mean python?

Tags: python

```
x=10, y=20
```

This is really short code, but when I execute this code in python, "can't assign to literal" error appears. Of course I know that this can't be executed in pyhon just intuitively, and it's out of question. This code should be changed to

```
x,y=10,20
```

or

```
x=10
y=20
```

like this. but I can't explain WHY the first code is error **logically**. please help me!

Comment: The expression `some_variable = some_literal ,` makes: `(some_literal,)`

Answer (score 6):

Your error is that you think `x=10, y=20` means `x=10; y=20` when in fact it means `x=(10, y)=20`.  This is because the comma creates a tuple, and you can't assign to a tuple which contains a literal (in this case `10`).

Answer (score 0):

What python does with this:

```
A, B = C, D
```

It assigns the first value to the first variable, and the second value to the second variable:

```
A = C
B = D
```

This works because python internally makes "tuples" with your values delimited by a comma:

```
(A, B) = (C, D)
```

When you do

```
A = C, B = D
```

Python believes that you are doing:

```
A = (C, B) = D
```

Or:

```
(C, B) = D   # Which is C = D[0] and B = D[1]
A = (C, B)
```

But `C` in you case is a number, not a variable, so:

```
x = 10, y = 20
```

Is:

```
x = (10, y) = 20
```

Or:

```
(10, y) = 20
x = (10, y)
```

Which is not possible. You can't assign something to a number (`10`). Doing `10 = 'something'` will give you `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`.

To make simpler, just execute in your python console:

```
10 = 1
```

And you will have the same error.